# How can I get selected Switch array list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I have an array list with UISwitch. How can I get an array list with UISwitch = ON when switch change to ON or OFF? I will use the list to display info in other ViewController.

**cell.m**

```
- (void) switchToggled:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

    if(theSwitch.on)
    {
        // switch turned on
        !_switchSelectCategoryClick ? : _switchSelectCategoryClick();
    }
    else
    {
        // switch turned off
        !_switchRemoveCategoryClick ? : _switchRemoveCategoryClick();
    }
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *gridcell = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.strCategoryName = [aryMerchantCategoryList [indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"category_name"];

        cell.switchSelectCategoryClick = ^{
            [aryMerchantCategoryList [indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"category_id"];
            //HOW CAN I STORE WHOLE UISWITCH = ON LIST HERE?
            }
        };
        cell.switchRemoveCategoryClick = ^{
            [aryMerchantCategoryList [indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"category_id"];
           //HOW CAN I STORE WHOLE UISWITCH = ON LIST HERE?
        };
        gridcell = cell;

    }

    return gridcell;
}
```

Comment: use a common array, and maintain index or id of switch in it.On add, add index in array and on remove remove that index

Comment: You could store selected category into an array on `switchSelectCategoryClick` and remove that on `switchRemoveCategoryClick` block. Pass that array while navigating to another viewController.

Comment: Hi @ShamimHossain, can you all show some sample code how can i achieve that?

Comment: Hi @Yatendra, can you all show some sample code how can i achieve that?